# R matrix whose 2nd column contains the squares of the numbers in the 1st column

Tags: r, matrix

I am new to R. I need to make a matrix in R whose 1st column contains the numbers 6,7,8,9 and whose 2nd column contains the squares of the numbers in the 1st column.

Comment: Try `x <- c(6,7,8,9);matrix(c(x, x^2), nrow = 4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible solutions to your problem. One way is to use [`cbind()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/combine-vectors-matrix-or-data-frames-by-columns-in-r-language-cbind-function/), e.g.

```r
mat <- matrix(6:9)
mat
#>      [,1]
#> [1,]    6
#> [2,]    7
#> [3,]    8
#> [4,]    9
mat2 <- cbind(mat, mat^2)
mat2
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    6   36
#> [2,]    7   49
#> [3,]    8   64
#> [4,]    9   81
```